# JavaScript endsWith is not working in IEv10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, prototypejs

I'm trying to compare two strings in JavaScript using endsWith(), like

```js
var isValid = string1.endsWith(string2);
```

It's working fine in Google Chrome and Mozilla. When comes to IE it's throwing a console error as follows

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'endsWith'
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Method **[`endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)** not supported in IE. Check [browser compatibility here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Browser_compatibility).

You can use polyfill option taken from [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Polyfill):

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchString, position) {
      var subjectString = this.toString();
      if (typeof position !== 'number' || !isFinite(position) 
          || Math.floor(position) !== position || position > subjectString.length) {
        position = subjectString.length;
      }
      position -= searchString.length;
      var lastIndex = subjectString.indexOf(searchString, position);
      return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
  };
}
```

Comment: It helps to know that this script can be placed anywhere. Ideally it is loaded as the page loads too so that it is made available to all other functions

Comment: Find the simplified answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544376/javascript-endswith-is-not-working-in-iev10#answer-37545037

Answer (score 18):

I found the simplest answer,

All you need do is to define the prototype

```js
 if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
   String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
     return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
   };
 }
```

Comment: Kudos. Anyway, I think `string.indexOf(suffix, string.length - suffix.length) !== -1;` is sufficient, since altering the prototype is a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

It's generally bad practise to extend the prototype of a native JavaScript object. See here - [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

You can use a simple check like this that will work cross-browser:

```
var isValid = (string1.lastIndexOf(string2) == (string1.length - string2.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Reaction on an old issue:
Elaborating on alternative for `endsWith()` in IE11.

To avoid that string1 = "a", string2 = "bc"; would return true:

```
var isValid = (string1.lastIndexOf(string2) == (string1.length - string2.length) && string1.lastIndexOf(string2) >= 0);
```